# Text editor which can directly search compressed text files? (only uncompressing them in memory)

Tags: text-editor

I have 20 GB of (uncompressed) log files. They're initially compressed though (as one 70 KB .gz file per log file) and total about 700 MB. I need to browse and search them to diagnose some issues. I don't know exactly what I'm searching for and I probably will need to quickly browse through a couple thousand hits for any search I try.

I tried doing this by uncompressing all of the files and then searching through them using Notepad++ or Visual Studio. The problem is that the searches are horrendously slow and put a lot of load on the hard disk. I assume that for every search I do, it needs to read all 20 GB from disk.

What might work better is if there's a text editor (or a Notepad++ plugin?) which can search inside .gz files without uncompressing them to disk. The 700 MB of .gz files can easily fit into system cache and I assume that uncompressing each file in memory would be much faster than reading an uncompressed file from disk.

I guess my alternative is to only work with a couple of gigs at a time so that all of it has a chance of being cached, but that would be pretty inconvenient. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Directly searching in compressed files might be hard to find (although it would be possible), perhaps look for an editor instead that doesn't load the whole file. For example, Total commander (http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) has a nice hex-viewer/editor built-in (F3) that loads big files in seconds and has search functionality.

Comment: Thanks schnaader. The problem though is that the editor has to read the entire file from disk in order to search the entire file. Since I'm searching 20 GB of text, it needs to read 20 GB from disk.

Comment: Do you need a text *editor* or a text *viewer*?

Comment: @liori - viewer. I said editor because viewers tend to be editors too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zless` from `cygwin` should be able to do this.

Comment: [zgrep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-grepping-compressed-files/) should be able to do this as well.

Comment: and [zcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zcat) as well

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `gunzip` and `grep` can do this:

```
gunzip -c *.gz | grep "Search for something"
```

Native windows versions available here:

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems like zgrep does the same thing. Is there an advantage of this over zgrep?

Comment: The native windows toolset doesn't include zgrep.  The other apps you mentioned indicated you're on Windows.

Comment: It looks like cygwin does have zgrep.

Comment: @jthg, personally I prefer native tools over abstraction layers, but either solution would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

jEdit supports opening/searching in compressed text files.

You can execute searching of directory and use *.gz in filter.

The result will be shown in HyperSearch panel.
When clicking in result, jEdit will open the decompressed file content in an editor panel and jump the the position where the text has been found.